# Strategy to keep local cache see the same "version" of data in a distributed system

Tags: database, architecture, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm trying to build a distributed system to run some performance intensive calculations. One calculation can be done in parallel at multiple worker nodes. The problem is, as the data source keeps changing in real-time, we want each worker node (during a single calculation) to operate on the same "version" of data, i.e. a point-in-time snapshot of the database. This is to avoid inconsistent results.

Another issue is, the entire set of input data per calculation can be very large, so currently we keep a local cache at each worker node, which refreshes the content periodically by asking the data source for "diffs" since the current local cache version and applies the diffs to the local cache.

What are some design strategies to achieve the requirement that each worker node sees the same "version" of data (while still have reasonably fresh data)? I have thought about a solution below but wanted to see if this is a common pattern that has been solved:

- Build a "versioning" service that periodically queries the data source for diffs and store each diff as a data "version". The worker node's caches sync with the versioning service and also keep its cached data at multiple versions. For one calculation, we make sure that the worker nodes use input data at the same version to achieve consistency. This versioning service should also keep the latest copy of the entire data set for the worker node to load its cache initially, and to restore the local cache content if a worker node goes down and goes back up.

Some estimated parameters of the system:

- Number of workers: 10
- Average job duration: obviously we want this to be as fast as possible, but let's say it should be less than 2 minutes
- Input data for a job (overall for all workers): ~100GB
- Size of the database: ~1TB

Comment: Please provide some numbers, for example: number of workers, avg. job duration, avg. calculation duration, size of the database. Also, what is large input data? Rough estimates are sufficient, as they probably help determine a good solution.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with some estimated numbers

Comment: As stated, this is too generic to answer properly. Basically you want to build a [multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) system. There is quite a few literature on the subject to get you started.

Comment: I think the requirements here are less complex than MVCC. It does not have to deal with writes (assuming writes still happen elsewhere), but the job engine just need to see a consistent point-in-time view when reading the data source (s).

Comment: You imply that without the writing capability (of some agents) it will be a simpler solution. However, you still need to extract 100 gb while writes might be happening. For that you'll either need to stop these writes while extraction is happening (lock, extract, unlock) or you'll need MVCC of sorts. As for simplicity, your main storage might already be using MVCC under the hood (e.g. in the form of supporting "snapshot isolation").

Comment: Reading the problem, looks like you need a map-reduce system or are you looking for something more complex than that?

Comment: Yeah let's say the main storage is MySql which has MVCC, but as far as I know, in mysql you cannot just snapshot a table and have multiple nodes read from that snapshot, that's why I'm thinking about having a separate (single-node) service that periodically pulls the snapshot from mysql and saves it somewhere else so that the worker nodes can read the same snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to MySQL and could to use Oracle there is a simple solution for you:

> [Oracle Flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008)

(I have not found MySQL flashback yet comment please if you know some motor for this.) You do not have to create a manual snapshot etc. You could use this with a single database server and all of your processes could read the data as it was represented in the requiried time. This solution is pretty clean and robust but requires licences.

If I were you I would try to take a step back and try to simplify the problem a bit more. If the different workers could run parallel the following should apply:

- None of the workers use the output of the others
- None of them is altering the original data

If both of those requirement is valid you could use a single database to store the calculations etc. The only thing You have to care about is that the transactions should be carefully planned.

On the other hand on a simmilar project we used a small trick to achive this (as the flashback solution): there was the insertion time stored in the database too. (And updates were actually inserts with new timestamps.) All of the calculations etc were made on accurate records by adding to the query the

> give me the last version of this kind of row before x timestamp

With this solution we avoided the licence costs and the snapshot maintanence. The only problem with this, if you do not need the whole history it will eat your database space pertty fast. To solve this we made a cron job that is clearing off the unused records based on the timestamp.

If you want to get more, there is something called shadow tables. There is a nice MySQL blog post on this topic:
http://arnab.org/blog/shadow-tables-using-mysql-triggers

Comment: By "you could use a single database to store the calculations" do you mean the storing the inputs to the calculations?

Comment: Actually both the inputs and outputs. If you got a bit more specific question I'll answer it tomorrow. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why we need to store the outputs. Storing the inputs seems similar to the approach I suggested in the question with the data snapshot service (or "versioning" service as I called it).

Comment: I just assumed, that it needs to be persisted somehow. :) Yeah the solution is mimicking the behaviour of the Oracle Flashback functionality. Personally I like the boxed Oracle, but I am kind of sad that Postgres had the same idea but failed to deliver it (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9059865.post@talk.nabble.com). The other solution (using triggers) is also a nice way, but it could be more resource consuming in terms of memory and/or CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are overcomplicating. For your task, you need to store and to differentiate only the current and the latest version of data. So, your script should:

1. mark latest data as currently used dataset
2. delete all older data
3. tell workers to use marked dataset
4. all this time, you add new data to tables (not update but add)
5. go to step 1

Comment: This approach requires changing the whole database schema (instead of updating an existing row, we keep adding new rows with new version number). This is not viable for us since our database schema is huge.

Comment: @Pinch your database schema may be huge but you only need to add two fields - timestamp and dataset id - to each table. Of cause, that's if you don't have complex relationships. Either way you can implement desirable behavior either with schema redesign or with expensive features of enterprise database. Oh, also you can make snapshots of production database and allow workers to work on snapshot. Through this will be also rather expensive.